# Identify Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, client-server

I've a python Socket server running and also socket clients.

Now, for example say there are 3 clients connected to same server. Please find below the code of the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module
import threading

serversocket = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 1234                # Reserve a port for your service.
serversocket.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
serversocket.listen(5)
print("Bound the port ",port,"on Machine : ",host,", and ready to accept connections.\n")

def clientThread(connection):
    while True:
        data=connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.send("Thanks")

    connection.close()

def sendMessage(connection, message):
    connection.send(message)

while 1:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientthread, (connection,))

serversocket.close();
```

Now, I need to call sendMessage for a particular client, say out of clients A,B and C, send it to B. In this case, how do I identify the thread and call that function?

Comment: You also might get some ideas from the single threaded chat server: http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Queues and multiple threads per connection to solve this problem.

Basic outline:

1. Each client connection spawns two threads - one to monitor client input and another which monitors a Queue. Items placed on the queue will be sent to the client. Each client connection will have its own output queue.
2. You'll also need a global dictionary to map a client name to their output queue.
3. To send a message to a particular client, find the client's output queue and add the message to it.
4. You'll also need a way to shutdown the output thread for a client. A common approach is to use a *sentinel* value (like `None`) on the queue to inform the output thread to exit its processing loop. When the client's input thread detects EOF it can place the sentinel value on the client's output queue and eventually the output thread will shut itself down.